# Import CSV: Is there a cap for number of row

Tags: qgis, csv, import

I am trying to import several CSV files which contain more than 1,000 rows respectively. 
However, but only 129 records were only imported each file.

Can't see any options that deal with this?

I am using Mac(10.7.5), QGIS 1.8.0-Lisboa, GDAL/OGR 1.9.1.
Anyone can advise me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen this behaviour in other software when the number of entries in a row doesn't match the number of field headers, or the data type changes at one line (ie a string field finding a numeric entry or visa versa).  You would be advised to examine the rows carefully, particularly if you are using a spreadsheet to create the *.csv since mixed data types are permitted in a column.

Comment: Many thanks. define the each header in Excel. and It works.